# IBM App Connect Rest RequestNode; Basic authorization

Tags: websphere, ibm-app-connect

Use IBM app connect to create a message flow. Within the message Flow, an API endpoint is being consumed but security is enabled on the endpoint. so I want to know how to add the username and password for the Request Node that connects to the API.

Didn't try anything yet because I don't know which root to take

Comment: Using IBM APP CONNECT ENTERPISE TOOLKIT send a message to a mqinput and the sending it to an restrequest node

Answer (score 0):

The basic "task" you need to follow is this one: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/12.0?topic=security-configuring-identity-propagation, the part you want to enable is the bit where it says `an output or request node can be configured to send a locally stored identity in the output message by configuring it with a security profile with propagation enabled, and the local identity referenced.`

So you'll want to register the u/p in the credential store (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/12.0?topic=security-configuring-identity-propagation#provide) (I'd suggest following the links to using the `mqsicredentials` approach rather than `mqsisetdbparms` as it provides better protection of your passwords, but ultimately it's all stored on disk in either case. Specifically, if you look in https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/12.0?topic=commands-mqsicredentials-command you want to register a `rest` credential type for an `External REST API`).

then once you've created a security profile referencing the stored credential, you can use that Security Profile from any node that needs to be able to use that particular identity to connect to a remote endpoint.

Hope this helps, I might have got one or two parameters wrong as I'm used to using the basic HTTP nodes rather than the REST nodes built on top.